# What is the tmux prefix code for command key on mac?

Tags: terminal, tmux, macintosh

I'd like to change my tmux prefix key from control to command (on mac).

I have an example on how to set it to alt:

```
set-option -g prefix M-b
```

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/259614/bind-tmux-prefix-to-os-x-cmd-key-or-any-other-binding

Comment: @NickODell I looked there, but noone talks about just setting the option

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`tmux` supports <kbd>Alt+key</kbd> (<kbd>Meta+key</kbd>) by prefixing the `key` with `M-`, or <kbd>Ctrl+key</kbd> with the `C-` prefix in the key binding specification.  There is no support for any other modifier keys.

Related question on the SuperUser site: [bind tmux prefix to OS X cmd key (or any other binding)](https://superuser.com/questions/259614/bind-tmux-prefix-to-os-x-cmd-key-or-any-other-binding)

Also this random Reddit post: [tmux on OS X: how to use the Cmd key with bind?](https://www.reddit.com/r/tmux/comments/1zzc3l/tmux_on_os_x_how_to_use_the_cmd_key_with_bind/)

The general gist of these posts is to rebind a macOS command key sequence with some other software to send an <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key sequence to `tmux`.

Comment: for some reason alt didn't work for me. ended up mapping the prefix to control-space on my mac. "set-option -g prefix C-Space"